# Vert.x RxJava2 return null for Handler<AsyncResult<Void>>

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

I'm struggling to convert the following snippet, which is converting the `resultHandler` to an observer and subscribing to the Single, to RxJava2, which doesn't support null.

```
@Override
  public WikiDatabaseService createPage(String title, String markdown, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler) {
    dbClient.rxUpdateWithParams(sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.CREATE_PAGE), new JsonArray().add(title).add(markdown))
      .map(res -> (Void) null)
      .subscribe(SingleHelper.toObserver(resultHandler));
    return this;
  }
```

Is anyone able to offer any advice?

Comment: The [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls) has suggestions for such cases.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to use `Observable.empty()` in lieu of `(Void) null`, where `toObserver(resultHandler)` is adapting a Vert.x `Handler<AsyncResult<T>>` to an RxJava2 `SingleObserver`.

Comment: Well, you don't need to map `res` to `null`; you just need to ensure that the `resultHandler` is passed a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toCompletable` with `CompletableHelper.toObserver`:

```
@Override
public WikiDatabaseService createPage(String title, String markdown, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler) {
  dbClient.rxUpdateWithParams(sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.CREATE_PAGE), new JsonArray().add(title).add(markdown))
    .toCompletable()
    .subscribe(CompletableHelper.toObserver(resultHandler));
  return this;
}
```

Make sure your project dependencies include the Vert.x RxJava2 module:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```